# Popular selects com php, jquery e mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, select

Boa tarde, colegas eu estou com uma duvida que há muito tempo venho tentando resolver e não consigo que é popular 4 selects usando php, mysql, ajax e jquery. Procurando por respostas no google eu encontrei um exemplo que ensina a popular 3 selects, e no exemplo você selecionava o país, depois o estado e por último a cidade. Só que 3 selects para mim, não serve pois para minha aplicação funcionar eu precisaria de pelo menos 4 selects, pois iria fazer da seguinte maneira: primeiro seleciona a marca do carro, segundo o modelo do carro, terceiro o ano do carro e por último o motor do carro apenas isso. Alguém pode me dar uma luz para esse problema?
Vou postar meus códigos
Index.php

```
    <?php 
    // Include the database config file 
    include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

    // Fetch all the marca data 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM marca WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY marca_name ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- marca dropdown -->
<select id="marca">
    <option value="">Selecione a marca</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['marca_id'].'">'.$row['marca_name'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Marcas não disponiveis</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>

<!-- carro dropdown -->
<select id="carro">
    <option value="">Selecione uma marca primeiro</option>
</select>

<!-- ano dropdown -->
<select id="ano">
    <option value="">selecione um carro primeiro</option>
</select>

<!-- motor dropdown -->
<select id="motor">
    <option value="">Selecione um ano primeiro</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#marca').on('change', function(){
        var marcaID = $(this).val();
        if(marcaID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'marca_id='+marcaID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#carro').html(html);
                    $('#ano').html('<option value="">Select ano first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#carro').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#ano').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
            $('#motor').html('<option value="">Selecione um ano primeiro</option>');
        }
    });

    $('#carro').on('change', function(){
        var carroID = $(this).val();
        if(carroID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'carro_id='+carroID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#ano').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#ano').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
            $('#motor').html('<option value="">Selecione um ano primeiro</option>');
        }
    });

    $('#ano').on('change', function(){
        var anoID = $(this).val();
        if(anoID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'ano_id='+anoID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#motor').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#ano').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
            $('#motor').html('<option value="">Selecione um ano primeiro</option>');
        }
    });



});
</script>
```

agora o ajaxData.php

```
    <?php 
// Include the database config file 
include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

if(!empty($_POST["marca_id"])){ 
    // Fetch state data based on the specific country 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM carro WHERE marca_id = ".$_POST['marca_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY carro_name ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 

    // Generate HTML of state options list 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select State</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['carro_id'].'">'.$row['carro_name'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>'; 
    } 
}elseif(!empty($_POST["carro_id"])){ 
    // Fetch city data based on the specific state 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ano WHERE carro_id = ".$_POST['carro_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY ano ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 

    // Generate HTML of city options list 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ano_id'].'">'.$row['ano'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">City not available</option>'; 
    } 
}

elseif(!empty($_POST["ano_id"])){ 
    // Fetch city data based on the specific state 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM motor WHERE motor_id = ".$_POST['motor_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY motor_id ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 

    // Generate HTML of city options list 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['motor_id'].'">'.$row['motor_name'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Motor não disponivel</option>'; 
    } 
}
?>
```

e agora a conexão com o mysql

```
<?php 
// Database configuration 
$dbHost     = "localhost"; 
$dbUsername = "root"; 
$dbPassword = ""; 
$dbName     = "carro"; 

// Create database connection 
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName); 

// Check connection 
if ($db->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error); 
}
```

toda vez que chega na parte do motor ele não carrega a lista de motores e não tenho ideia do que pode ter acontecido. Muito grato pela resposta

Comment: Você não definiu o evento `onChange ` para o motor e consulta para o ano está misturada com a consulta do motor.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, vou tentar corrigir este erro

Comment: mas se faz com dois faz com qtos precisar, a lógica é a mesma, não precisa de um exemplo com exatos 4. só colocar uma chamada ajax no onchange do primeiro, que carrega o segunto, no onchange do 2 outro ajax que carrega o terceiro, e assim por diate, pra quantos precisar